How are Python methods passed as function arguments still aware of their instance (self) context?
I have encountered what would reduce to the following code
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width, **kwargs):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def perform_hello(self):
        def print_properties():
            print(self.length, self.width)
        Utility.hello(print_properties)


class Utility:
    @staticmethod
    def hello(f):
        f()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Rectangle(2, 5).perform_hello() # outputs 2, 5

A function is passed as an argument to a static method; this method can be executed and also is aware of its parent object properties.
I am not sure how to understand this from an object oriented perspective, or maybe it is a Python behavior that I'm not grasping well?
If I were to try and do the same "naively", it doesn't seem to work
class Square():
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = self.width = length

    def perform_hello(self, f):
        f()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = print(self.length, self.width)
    Square(4).perform_hello(f)

Which leaves me confused.

print_properties is closed over self; when you pass it to Utility.hello it would be "aware of" any other local variables, including non-self parameters. This isn't particular to methods or their instance.

A nested function has access to the local variables of its containing function - normally read-only, unless there's a nonlocal declaration.  print_properties() can therefore use the self variable from the specific call to perform_hello() that defined it.

print_properties is not a method.

Thank you; my question was also whether the passing of a method this way could be purely functional. If it was, I would suppose my later example may have worked. As I now understand, method objects simply are aware of their enclosing context, even though they are completely taken apart in a different place.
